# Should I put a comma after a phrase "given ..."?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

I have the following sentence:

> The result can be phrased as the statement that given an integer n the equation x^n = y has a solution.

I was wondering is it better to put a comma like "given an integer n, [...]" or keep it like this? Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single comma is used to separate clauses. I don't think this is two separate clauses. I think what you are trying to do is highlight a parenthetic statement, which would require two commas.

A parenthetic statement is one that can be enclosed in commas or brackets.

For example:

- The result can be phrased as the statement that, given an integer n, the equation x^n = y has a solution.
- The result can be phrased as the statement that (given an integer n) the equation x^n = y has a solution.

It should be possible to completely remove a parenthetic statement and the sentence would still make sense, which yours seems to:

- The result can be phrased as the statement that the equation x^n = y has a solution.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh This is an English grammar site. If you think a Maths textbook is wrong, find a mathematics site and ask them about terminology.

Comment: The statements are written in English even though it is a Mathematics textbook. Hence I pointed out. And OP's question does contain Math since there is exponential functions used. So I am guessing he is either asking this for his assignment/study related issues or might be for writing a research paper.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Yes in English, but each field of study has its own *terminology*. Terminology doesn't always follow the rules of English grammar, and often words or phrases have different meanings in different fields. The example I always give, as I work in the field of IT, is the word "unresolved" which has a very different meaning in ITIL terminology to its dictionary definition. I know my answer is correct grammatically, but if you see it written differently in a mathematics textbook you should talk to a mathemetician.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.