# Comma after a sentence starting with "Given [...]"

Tags: grammar, commas

If I have a sentence starting with "Given [..]" does it make sense to put a comma? I have two sentences as below. I think the commas here make sense to put commas here.

Given an integer n, the equation x^n = y has a solution.
Also given an integer m, the equation x-m = y has a solution.

This is similar to my previous question
[Should I put a comma after a phrase "given ..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263963/should-i-put-a-comma-after-a-phrase-given/263970#263970)
but since the situation is a bit different I want to clarify. In particular, for the second sentence should one put a comma after 'also' as well? or is this unnecessary? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I put a comma after a phrase "given ..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263963/should-i-put-a-comma-after-a-phrase-given)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate. In my answer, which you accepted, I explained the difference between using a single comma and parenthesis. If you research that further you will have an answer to this question. Asking if something is correct is off-topic here.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me because in this situation the phrase is in the beginning of the sentence, hence it can't be placed between two commas. Does a single comma work as enclosing it in two commas in this situation?